# mirror gitlab wiki to github

Tags: git, github, gitlab, wiki

We are developing a software on a private GitLab server. 
Nobody from outside has access to this server.

Now we somehow have to make our software available for everybody. 
Our Idea is to mirror the repository to GitHub which should be possible due to some research we did.

We also maintain a wiki in GitLab. 
Is it also possible to mirror our GitLab wiki pages to GitHub?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [Github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-and-editing-wiki-pages-locally/#cloning-wikis-locally-to-your-computer) and [Gitlab](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/412#note_3572096) wikis are repositories with URLs like `https://git$b.com/$user/$project.wiki.git` so you clone your wiki from Gitlab and push to Github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Github Wiki](https://docs.github.com/en/communities/documenting-your-project-with-wikis/about-wikis) or you can also use [Github Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages), you can restrict access to your project site by publishing the site privately.