# Is the Git history of my GitLab wiki open to abuse?

Tags: git, security, gitlab, wiki

I have enabled the wiki component of my GitLab project. As with any wiki, it is open to abuse by any user with permission to edit it via the web interface.

Trivial abuse can be resolved by a new edit. Because the wiki is backed by a Git repository, major abuse can be (relatively) easily resolved by reverting to a previous version.

However, what about abuse of the Git history of the wiki itself? Are there any mechanisms in place to prevent, for example, arbitrary pushes that wipe both the wiki and its Git history?

*(Note I am only asking about the wiki repo for the project, not the code repo for the project.)*

Comment: Read *[How GitLab Permissions and Protected Branches Keep Your Code Safe](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)* and apply suitable limits on users. If a user has permission to force push and thus wipe out everything then they can wipe out everything.

Comment: @Richard I can only see one reference to a project wiki (rather than project code) here https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/#how-we-define-permissions -- does this imply that only developers can push to the wiki repo?

Comment: Given underneath the wiki it is git I expect the same rules apply

Comment: At Github and Gitlab [wikis are repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173883/7976758).